# CSS selector for all elements beginning with app- prefix

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm trying to target all app- prefixed elements in my Angular application. Does anyone know a method in SCSS or vanilla CSS to target elements this way?

Please don't recommend using class or attribute targeting like `[class^="app-"]` I'm trying to avoid adding them.

Comment: It was answered just fine by @muhammedAlbararmawi. I dont see your answer anywhere?

Comment: If specifying a list of all Angular components by hand was an option, Sass barely helps there. You can just do `app-home, app-login, app-other { color: red }`, it's actually **less** to do than creating a list and iterating over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know there 's no solution in `css` but in `sass` you can use list to store your components name and loop throw the list and create the desire selector.

> but with this way you have to add the components name manually

```
$component-list : 'home','admin' , 'other';
$prefix : 'app';


@each $c in $component-list {
  #{$prefix}-#{$c}{
   color:red;
  }
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sass-list)

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer to my specific question. It looks as though I will have to target each component selector so sass list is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such CSS selector. As you suggest, you can only do it with an attribute selector and `^=`.

An alternative would be to use JavaScript:

```
const components = Array.prototype.filter.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  e => e.tagName.toLowerCase().startsWith('app-')
)
```

You could now easily do `components.forEach(cmp => cmp.classList.add('__angular-component'))`, and then from CSS do `.__angular-component { background: red }` or whatever.

Comment: Solid answer, thank you @Lazar. However I'll need to add each component to my global stylesheet in order to stay away from adding attributes to my markup.